# what is happen for H2 database used in wso2 in production environment

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

> Hi,
>               what is happen for h2 database used in wso2 in production environment 
>           can we run wso2 with out database dependency.

Comment: Can you try to be more specific on what you want to know? It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: I want use in built database in wso2 but some wso2 document saying strongly recommended we should not use inbuilt  database (h2). i want know that will happen if we use this one.

Comment: @Narasimha, Provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using H2 database isn't specific to WSO2 products. It's problem in H2 database itself.

H2 database isn't reliable to use in any production environment.

> The H2 documentation explains in detail several ways in which problems
>   in underlying hardware and in particular power systems can impact
>   durability of relational databases.
>
> According to the H2 documentation, such problems are related not only
>   to the DB engine design, but also to the storage caching mechanism. As
>   storage devices use write cache in order to increase speed, in a
>   situation of power failure, data in the device's cache is lost.
>   Administrators have then to assess the common trade off between speed
>   and data loss risks in the context of the business requirements and
>   must carefully consider the design of the power supply and UPS of
>   critical servers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)

Comment: Thank very much your answer.. i have one more question can we run wso2 with out  using any database ?.

Comment: Nope, but for non-prod deployments, you can use H2 database which is embedded in the product.